# Json list comparison - SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

I'm using SQL Server 2016, and currently involved in storing, retrieving and parsing JSON data. My question is on list comparison.

**Sample Data :** Table has 2 columns

```
Column1 - Data = 'Microsoft'  
Column2 - Data = '{"info":{"type":1,"address":   {"town":"Bristol","county":"Avon","country":"England"},"tags":["Sport", "Water polo"]},"type":"Basic"}'
```

**Query :**

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(Column2, '$.info.tags') from dbo.sample_table;
```

**Output :**

```
["Sport", "Water polo"]
```

How do I match if I need to check for **["Water polo","Sport"]** ? Does JSON library in SQL Server 2016 allow checking array content irrespective of order of data ?

TIA

Comment: can you please elaborate on this `How do I match if I need to check for ["Water polo","Sport"] `

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: [Query in to JSON Arrays in SQL 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44051567/json-functions-in-sql-server-2016/44051859#44051859)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, you need to compare the array of `tags` within your JSON structure. If the order of tags is irrelevant you could convert your `tags` array into a table result set and use standard `where value in (select...` SQL clause.

The first thing is to convert tags into SQL result set:

```
SELECT TagsData.[value]
FROM sample_table T CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (T.Column2, '$.info.tags') AS TagsData
```

..then you need to compare it against anything you have. E.g. for testing purposes I'm using locally declared JSON string:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(4000) = N'
    {
        "info":{"type":1,"address": {"town":"Bristol","county":"Avon","country":"England"},
        "tags":["Water polo", "Sport"]},"type":"Basic"
    }';

SELECT [value]
FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.info.tags')
```

(notice the changed order of `["Water polo", "Sport"]`)

..and testing if it is *not* contained within the `Column2`:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(4000) = N'
    {
        "info":{"type":1,"address": {"town":"Bristol","county":"Avon","country":"England"},
        "tags":["Water polo", "Sport"]},"type":"Basic"
    }';

SELECT [value]
FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.info.tags')
where [value] not in
(
SELECT TagsData.[value]
FROM TestTable T CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (T.Column2, '$.info.tags') AS TagsData
)
```

If the result set is empty - your arrays are the same and they do match (irrespective of their order). If the result set contains any data - it represents an actual difference of those two JSON arrays.